# Make anonymous call to Server in ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor App

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor Webassembly app from the included template in VS with Authorization and ASP.NET Core hosted options as shown here:

[image: Create Blazor dialog]

I want to be able to make http requests to the server without being authenticated. I changed the code in the `WeatherForecastController`by commenting out the `[Authorize]` attribute (and even added an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute):

```
//[Authorize] CHANGED
[AllowAnonymous] //CHANGED
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

In the `FetchData.razor` page, along with other changes noted in the code, I commented out `@attribute [Authorize]`:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using StackOverflowAuthProblem.Shared
@*@attribute [Authorize]*@ @*CHANGED*@
@inject HttpClient Http

@*CHANGED Html removed for brevity*@

<div>Exception message: @exceptionMessage</div>

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    string exceptionMessage; //CHANGED

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
        }
        catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
        {
            exceptionMessage = exception.Message; //CHANGED returns an empty string

            exceptionMessage = exception.ToString(); //CHANGED returns
                //Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AccessTokenNotAvailableException: '' at
                //Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
                //CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(
                //    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                //at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request,
                //HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop,
                //CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
                //at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__9`1[[StackOverflowAuthProblem.Shared.WeatherForecast[],
                //StackOverflowAuthProblem.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
                //at StackOverflowAuthProblem.Client.Pages.FetchData.OnInitializedAsync()
                //in E:\StackOverflow\StackOverflowAuthProblem\StackOverflowAuthProblem\Client\Pages\FetchData.razor:line 53

            //exception.Redirect(); CHANGE
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I get is in the code above. I suspect the problem is in the `App.razor` page, but can't figure it out.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: https://chrissainty.com/avoiding-accesstokennotavailableexception-when-using-blazor-webassembly-hosted-template-with-individual-user-accounts/

Reason: The default configuration in the template uses an HTTP client with a custom message handler called BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler. This handler attempts to attach an access token to any outgoing requests and if it can't find one, it throws an exception.

Solution:

First create a class

```
public class PublicClient
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public PublicClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        Client = httpClient;
    }
}
```

Register the class with Dependency Injection in the start up

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<PublicClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
```

Use it in razor pages

```
@inject PublicClient PublicClient
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted then deleted an answer here which said the problem was in following line in the `Program.cs` file of the client project:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("RclConsumer.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new 
   Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

Surely there's something I'm missing, otherwise can't help but think this is a major oversight that one can't hit an API endpoint without being authenticated.

```
public static class HttpClientService
{
    public static HttpClient AnonymousHttpClient { get; set; }

    static HttpClientService()
    {
        AnonymousHttpClient = new HttpClient();

#if DEBUG
        AnonymousHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44395/");
#else
        throw new Exception("Need the Base address here");
#endif

    }
}
```

My reasoning for putting it in it's own class library is that I plan on adding Razor Class Libraries and I want a single instance of the `HttpClient` to use across the solution because of the [problem with sockets](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong)